# Splitting String Variable Into New Variables

Tags: python, list, variables

I am creating a script that splits the user input into letters, I have gotten this part down, however, how do I turn these separated letters into individual variables?

```
message = input("Enter Message)  ")
list = list(message)
print(list)
```

Whilst this does print out the typed string into letters, I want to know how to turn those split letters into their own variables. e.g `(h, e, l, l, o)` Is there a way that I can, for example, only print the first letter or the second letter? (so that the letters are split into their own variables)

Comment: I don't think you want to do that. You already have the individual letters in your list.

Comment: You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the list as a set 'own variables' (accessing them by index).

```
message = input("Enter Message)  ")
l = list(message)  # do not use reserved words, as 'list' for variable names
print(l)

print(l[0])  # prints the 1st letter
print(l[1])  # prints the 2nd letter
print(l[-1])  # prints the last letter
print(l[-2])  # prints the letter prior to the last
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some examples:

```
message = input("Enter Message)  ")

message_characters = list(message)  # do not use single characters as variable names

for i, char in enumerate(message_characters):
    print(f'The {i}{"th" if i>2 or i==0 else "nd" if i==2 else "st"} character is {char}')


# Though note that strings are also iterable:
for i, char in enumerate(message):
    print(f'The {i}{"th" if i>2 or i==0 else "nd" if i==2 else "st"} character is {char}')
```